# Amazon Simple Pay - Send Up User Data

Tags: grails, paypal-ipn, payment-processing

I am trying to integrate my web app with Amazon Simple Pay, so that users can pay for added functionality on the website.

Once a user makes a payment, I need to update that user in the database to mark them as being paid. It seems, however, like I can't send up any data, like the `USER ID`, so when my IPN comes back from Amazon, I don't know how to link the payment information with the user.  How can I do this?

Comment: Simple Pay should be sending information to your return URL, including their `transactionId`, which will also be in the IPN data.  You can use that ID to tie together the IPN and the customer.  You may need to [review the Simple Pay Advanced User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimplePay/latest/ASPAdvancedUserGuide/CapturingData.html).

Comment: @Charles But how do I tie the transactionId to a User? If the user makes a payment in Amazon, but closes their browser before the "return URL" is called, then I can't tie the `tranactionID`to a User, right?

Comment: Yeah, but if you get an IPN submission for a `transactionId` that you don't have a record for, you should raise an error on your end and investigate what failed.

Comment: @Charless - but the fact that they didn't call the `returnURL` isn't really a "failure" right? The user is within their right to close the browser. Are you saying that if that happens, then I get a `transactionID` that I can't account for, I should look at the Amazon transaction and try to figure out who in my application paid or something? I am not sure what to do in that business case, since I don't know who would have paid it or how to contact them.

Comment: This is going to be a manual thing, because while the user *can* close their browser, they *shouldn't*.  They have an account with you *before* you send them to pay, right?  And you have the local order record, right?  If so, then you have their subtotal, which should be (er, maybe?) included in the IPN, right?  I don't know that last one is true, now that I think about it.  Regardless, if users close their browser *before* getting confirmation that their order is placed, you should treat that as an error condition and not accept their money... IMO.

Comment: @Charles Thank you for all of your replies. I don't have a local order record before they go to Amazon to pay. I just have them click the supplied Amazon button and it takes them to the Amazon site. I am relying on the `returnURL` call to come back and be in the same session they had before, so I know to identify that return to the user whose session it is. Other way I have no way of knowing who to tie the payment to. Maybe you are right, that if they close the browser while the payment is going through then it is an error case. Thanks again.